# How do I fix this error in xcode 6.3 ios 8.3 Swift?

Tags: xcode, swift

I get  a whole bunch of errors when I updated Xcode to 6.3 and I fixed most of them except for this one. What am I doing wrong? Thank you!

```
 <NSObject> does not have a member named anyObject


 var touch: UITouch = touches.anyObject() as! UITouch
```

Comment: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch04.html#_set

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's now using `Set<NSObject>`, so you don't have `anyObject` anymore. But you can just grab the first item quite easily:

```
let touch = touches.first as! UITouch
```